# XML equivalent for a JSON input in Web API

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-web-api2, mediatypeformatter

I have the following JSON structure which is input for my Web API

```
{
    field1: "value1",
    field2: [
        { field2_1: "aaaa", field2_2: "bbbb", field2_3: "cccc" }
    ],
    field3: []
}
```

The API I am calling supports either JSON as well as XML.
How should I convert this structure in XML if I want to invoke the same api by sending XML instead of json?

Comment: I guess you can achieve this with JSON deserialization followed by XML Serialization.

Comment: Doesn't your web api have a help page? That shows an example. Is your client using HttpClient? That has XML or Json options.

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger: I am sorry but not. The web API does not have a help page.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois: What do you mean? Could you please further explain your suggestion?

Comment: How do you make the call with Json?

Comment: @Lorenzo You can Deserialize your JSON structur into a class With ( following your sample) a string, a list of string, and an array. Then with that class ( filed by your JSON ) you serialize it to XML format. https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx AND https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412179(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger: I am serializing the JSON into a string and passing it in a query string parameter. The WEB API is a GET method which accept the paraemeter on the query string

Answer (score 1):

You would need to refer to the WebAPI to determine this. I assume you would need some type of root element. But this is how I would format it:

```
<root>
   <field1>value1</field1>
   <field2>
      <element>
         <field2_1>aaaa</field2_1>
         <field2_2>bbbb</field2_2>
         <field2_3>cccc</field2_3>
      </element>
      <element>
         <field2_1>aaaa</field2_1>
         <field2_2>bbbb</field2_2>
         <field2_3>cccc</field2_3>
      </element>
   </field2>
   <field3 />
</root>
```

or

```
<root>
   <field1>value1</field1>
   <elements>
      <field2>
         <field2_1>aaaa</field2_1>
         <field2_2>bbbb</field2_2>
         <field2_3>cccc</field2_3>
      </field2>
      <field2>
         <field2_1>aaaa</field2_1>
         <field2_2>bbbb</field2_2>
         <field2_3>cccc</field2_3>
      </field2>
   </elements>
   <field3 />
</root>
```

Comment: Well. This is exactly the way I am trying. However the main problem is that field2 is an array and I dont' know how the represent it. In your suggestion, for example, how will you represent an array of field2 with more than one element?

Comment: You need to define the element array, or wrap each field2 in it's own element name. Please see my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my Web API. On the API provider web site all the samples are in JSON and they say that their code also works with XML. So I can't define any element

Comment: Well, without much more info, this problem is hard to solve. Perhaps you can post the JSON examples or link to the API so we can have a look.

Comment: Agreed. If they don't tell you what the XML structure is, it's hard to guess. Are you able to Get similar structure in XML? Maybe same structure is used for Get and POST/PUT.